# pl/pgsql Return true if update was successful

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

Given the following skeleton pl/pgsql function, how can I make it return `true` if the update was successful (something was actually updated) and false otherwise?

```
CREATE FUNCTION UpdateThingy(
    /* input parameters */
) RETURNS BOOLEAN AS $$
BEGIN
    UPDATE thingies SET /* blah blah */ WHERE /* blah blah */;
    RETURN true;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Currently this will always return `true`, even if no rows where updated. I want to return `false` in the case of no rows being affected by the update.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After the UPDATE, you can obtain the number of updated rows using `GET DIAGNOSTICS` or the `FOUND` status variable as described in the manual:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-DIAGNOSTICS

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE public."ChangePassword"(
    IN id int,
    IN pwd text,
    OUT affectedrows int)
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
AS $BODY$
BEGIN

    UPDATE "UserProfile" SET "Password" = pwd WHERE "Id" = id;
    GET DIAGNOSTICS affectedrows := ROW_COUNT;

END
$BODY$;
```

After executing the stored procedure in below way, it will return the affected row count(s), if any.

[image]